# Creating an API (in cakephp 1.3) and Delivering HTML

Tags: php, api, cakephp-1.3, mashup

This is not truly an API scenario. I know APIs deliver content in XML or JSON. I am not looking for someone to tell me how to do this but to give me a good starting point and some tips or tell me this is a stupid idea.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

1. Client User needs to be created through another website
2. Client needs to be authenticated through another website
3. Client needs to request pages that are HTML.
4. Client will need to save data to our database from these pages.
5. We will need to track each created user

We want the person implementing this "api" to their site to be required to have as little programming knowledge as possible.

Your input is greatly appreciated and valued. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you "requesting HTML" every time you vist a web site? Also you can't save to a database using pure HTML.

Comment: The problem here is that they have to request this html from a different domain than the one that holds the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my best solution will be to use an iframe.